# Implementing search by field of custom component in BizFx tool - Sitecore Commerce 9.0.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I would need to implement search in BizFx tool by one field that is element/field of my custom component in Sitecore Commerce. 
Here is json representation of Components element of SellableItem from database:

```
"Components":{  
  "$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Component, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
  "$values":[  
     {  
        "$type":"Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.ManagedLists.ListMembershipsComponent, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.ManagedLists",
        "Memberships":{  
           "$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
           "$values":[  
              "SellableItems",
              "CatalogItems"
           ]
        },
        "Id":"f4deca2b02904894bbbac881db7f67b5",
        "Name":"",
        "Comments":"",
        "Policies":{  
           "$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Policy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
           "$values":[  

           ]
        },
        "ChildComponents":{  
           "$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Component, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
           "$values":[  

           ]
        }
     },
     {  
        "$type":"CustomNamespace.Commerce.Plugin.Model.CommonComponent, CustomNamespace.Commerce.Plugin.Model",
        "CustomNewIdentifier":"111222333",
        "Id":"8de810f441b24201b4c66bdf136c43f6",
        "Name":"",
        "Comments":"",
        "Policies":{  
           "$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Policy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
           "$values":[  

           ]
        },
        "ChildComponents":{  
           "$type":"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Component, Sitecore.Commerce.Core]], mscorlib",
           "$values":[  

           ]
        }
     }

  ]
```

}

SellableItem contains custom component which type is CustomNamespace.Commerce.Plugin.Model.CommonComponent. This CommonComponent contains element CustomNewIdentifier. I have to implement search of SellableItems in BizFx tool by this custom element.
[image]

I tried to add in PlugIn.Search.PolicySet-1.0.0.json new field CustomNewIdentifier. Here is part of this json:

```
{
    "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.IndexablePolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search",
    "SearchScopeName": "ourcustomCatalogItemsScope",
    "Properties": {
      "EntityId": {
        "TypeName": "System.String",
        "IsKey": false,
        "IsSearchable": true,
        "IsFilterable": false,
        "IsSortable": false,
        "IsFacetable": false,
        "IsRetrievable": true
      },
      "SitecoreId": {
        "TypeName": "System.String",
        "IsKey": true,
        "IsSearchable": true,
        "IsFilterable": false,
        "IsSortable": false,
        "IsFacetable": false,
        "IsRetrievable": true
      },
      "ProductId": {
        "TypeName": "System.String",
        "IsKey": false,
        "IsSearchable": true,
        "IsFilterable": false,
        "IsSortable": false,
        "IsFacetable": false,
        "IsRetrievable": true
      },
      "CustomNewIdentifier": {
        "TypeName": "System.String",
        "IsKey": false,
        "IsSearchable": true,
        "IsFilterable": false,
        "IsSortable": false,
        "IsFacetable": false,
        "IsRetrievable": true
      }

    }
  }
```

Of course, I did deployment of SC Commerce and Bootstrapping Environment after adding this element into IndexablePolicy. But that didn't help. Search by custom field doesn't work.

I followed instructions described in these pages:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/setting-up-a-search-index.html

Has anyone implemented something similar?

Comment: Did you add Index minion policies and configure minion pipelines?
If yes, try to `Run FullIndex Minion - Catalog Items` from postman and when it will be completed - try to search again by your custom data

Comment: I've just defined Search Scope policy, Indexable policy, Search View policy. Are those index minion polices/pipelines already configured in Search plugin by default?

Comment: I think you need to complete all three steps from the documentation